# ImportError: No module named geographiclib.geodesic

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I am trying to run .py script file ,I am getting this error.  In the script file  after import the packages, I am written "from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic"

Answer (score 1):

You might have to install the module `geographiclib` by running

`pip install geographiclib`

or

`easy_install geographiclib`

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the issue below are the step which i follow to reslove.
1. Install PIP using command "python get-pip.py". you can download the get-pip.py file from internet.
2. Then run "pip install geographiclib". 
3.finish